# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\oci8_12c (The specified module could not be found

Tags: xampp, oci8, php-8.1

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\oci8_12c (The specified module could not be found

I'm trying to enable oci8_12c extension with Instant client 12.2 in PHP 8.1.2 on windows 10 x64

I've uncommented extension=oci8_12c in my php.ini file and downloaded and placed php_oci8-3.2.1-8.1-ts-vs16-x64 files in my C:\xampp\php\ext folder
and downloaded instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip file and extracted to C:\instantclient_12_2 also added to PATH.
at the end I restarted my PC.
but I got below error
"PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\oci8_12c (The specified module could not be found"

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this issue I have got.

Comment: I have the same problem with Xampp 8.1.17: neither the oci8_12c (added to the package) nor the oci8_19 (bundled with the package) are loaded, after enabled in the php.ini file. The phpinfo file indicates that these extensions are not being loaded.